# How can get rid of the multiply Intents

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have 2 activities. And I need pass a lot of variables from one activity to another activity:

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT1, accoun1)
            intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT2, accoun2)
            intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT3, accoun3)
            intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT4, accoun4)
            intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT5, accoun5)
            intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT6, accoun6)
            intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT7, accoun7)
            intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT8, accoun8)
            intent.putExtra(ACCOUNT9, accoun9)
```

and so on. How can I make this transfer easier? Maybe is some other ways to pass multiply values from one activity to another activity?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar case.

How I solved:

I created an entity that kept all the information for me, that way, I just passed an object between activities, but I had everything I needed inside that object.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `bundleOf` function in the Jetpack `core-ktx` library that works like `mapOf`.

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
val extras = bundleOf(
    ACCOUNT1 to accoun1,
    ACCOUNT2 to accoun2,
    ACCOUNT3 to accoun3,
    // etc.
)
intent.putExtras(extras)
```

But that doesn't save much code compared to just using `apply` unless you use the same bundle of extras in multiple places in your code:

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra(ACCOUNT1, accoun1)
    putExtra(ACCOUNT2, accoun2)
    putExtra(ACCOUNT3, accoun3)
    //...
}
```

You could make a parcelable data class that stores all your values and pass that instead. See instructions here for creating the class easily: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize

```
@Parcelize
data class AccountInfo(
    val account1: String,
    val account2: String,
    val account3: String,
    //...
): Parcelable
```

Then you can put this into your bundles, and you don't have to create a bunch of the same kinds of variables in both activities, because all the variables are inside one class.

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra(ACCOUNT_INFO, myAccountInfoInstance)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if all of your variables has the same type you can add all to list and pass the list to second activity/fragment.